# How to merge dataframe and series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe` and a `series` which are as following.

```
_df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, '', '', 4], 'b': ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'pear']}, columns=['a', 'b'])
_series = pd.Series(['', 2, 3, ''], name="a")
```

Here I would like to merge the `dataframe` and `series` along column `a` to get rid of all the blanks. This is the result I want.

```
   a    b
0  1  apple
1  2  banana
2  3  orange
3  4  pear
```

Here is how I do it.

```
for i in range(len(_df.iloc[:, 0].to_list())):
    if _df.iloc[i, 0] == '':
       _df.iloc[i, 0] = df_series[i]
```

Problem is it can be very slow if the `dataframe` is big. Anyone knows if I can do this in a more efficient way?

Comment: `df = df.assign(c=pd.combine_first(df["a"], _series))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.combine`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine.html) with lambda function for test not empty strings:

```
df = _df.assign(a=_df["a"].combine(_series, lambda x, y: x if x != '' else y))
print (df)
   a       b
0  1   apple
1  2  banana
2  3  orange
3  4    pear
```

Or [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) with replace empty strings to missing values:

```
df = _df.assign(a=_df["a"].replace('', np.nan).combine_first(_series.replace('', np.nan)))
print (df)
     a       b
0  1.0   apple
1  2.0  banana
2  3.0  orange
3  4.0    pear
```

For new column name `c` from variable `a` use:

```
a = 'c'
df = _df.assign(**{f'{a}': _df["a"].combine(_series, lambda x, y: x if x != '' else y)})
print (df)
```

Or:

```
a = 'c'

_df[f'{a}'] =  _df["a"].combine(_series, lambda x, y: x if x != '' else y)
print (_df)
   a       b  c
0  1   apple  1
1     banana  2
2     orange  3
3  4    pear  4
```

Comment: Can we use a variable after `df.assign` instead of the column name `a` here?

Comment: @haojie - Sure, use `_df.assign(c=_df["a"].combine(_series, lambda x, y: x if x != '' else y))` for assign to column `c`

Comment: In this way we would have a new column `c`. I mean can we use a pseudocode like `df.assign(f'{a}'=_df["a"].combine(_series, lambda x, y: x if x != '' else y))`

Comment: Appreciate your help~

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas `merge`:

```py
df = _df.merge(_series, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df['a_x'] = df['a_x'].astype(str) + df['a_y'].astype(str)
df.rename(columns={'a_x': 'a'}).drop(columns=['a_y'])
```

***Output:***

[image: result]